# Записать в базу имя каждого админа при каждом входе sql c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Добрый вечер.Есть две разные админы, и они заходят под разным логинам и паролям. При каждом входе надо записывать в базу логин этого админа. Сам запрос проверил в SQLite browser работает правильно.Скорей всего ошибка в C#. Заходят но не записывается, в sqlite browser я проверил INSERT INTO TempOutcomes(UserId) SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id=@id запрос, работает правильно. Заранее спасибо. Вот код:

```
string queryInsert = "INSERT INTO  TempOutcomes(UserId) SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Id=@id";
                            if (combo == 1)
                            {
                                Hide();
                                AdminForm admin = new AdminForm();
                                admin.Show();
                                try
                                {
                                    connection.Open();
                                    command = new SQLiteCommand(queryInsert, connection);
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", combo);
                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
                                finally { connection.Close(); }
                            }
                            else if (combo == 2)
                            {
                                Hide();
                                WorkerForm worker = new WorkerForm();
                                worker.Show();
                                try
                                {
                                    connection.Open();
                                    command = new SQLiteCommand(queryInsert, connection);
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", combo);
                                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
                                finally { connection.Close(); }
                            }
```

Comment: Если у вас winforms то вы не видите текст ошибки - потому что выводите его в консоль, которой у winforms нет. Переделайте на MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) и покажите нам текст ошибки.

Comment: И тот стиль написания кода, который вы используете он настолько неудобен для поиска ошибок и для удобной отладки, что у меня вызывает автоматический рефлекс переписать его в более простом стиле. Скажите, вам самому удобно работать со своим кодом?

Comment: у меня код вообще не так расположен,  для вопроса я сделал так, а насчёт ошибки написано: "Операция является не допустимой из-за текушего состояния обьекта"

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, почему нельзя было нарезать код этой функции на отдельные блоки - например, создать отдельный метод посчёта числа логинов private int UserCount(string login, string password) и вынести туда return ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; На нём падает или после? Если бы вы разделили длинный метод в триста строк на отдельные компактные методы по 5 строчек - можно было легко определить на каком методе падает и постепенно идти от одного к другому. А в этом лапшекоде без конца и края вы будете долго ковыряться.

Comment: Итого. Вопрос можно закрыть, т.к. [при составлении минимального примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/793081/213987) автор сам нашёл ошибку, вызванную опечаткой.

Comment: решил проблему. я два раза sqliteconnection открывал, поэтому не работал, а щась работает. Огромное спасибо вам за подсказку. – Исмоил Мухаммадиев 9 минут назад